# How do I fetch data from firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to swift and I am trying to do as best as I can not to bother others I have looked for days to solve a problem but still hopeless, I hope you guys could tell me how can I fix it.

I want to get data and to put it in newPerson enter code here`newPersons.append(nyPerson!)` and it crashes saying `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            self.ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "personer")
            self.ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                var newPersons:[BackUp] = []
                for item in snapshot.children {
                    let nyPerson = BackUp(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
                    newPersons.append(nyPerson!)

                }
                self.personsArray = newPersons
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
```

Comment: Make sure your 'nyPerson' is not nil. '!' force unwraps the value, and if it nil, it will crash

Comment: that's the problem it always shows nil

Answer (score 0):

This is a code form Getting Started documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data

I think the issue you have in BackUp.init(snapshot: DataSnapshot). be sure to get data with as optional, for example:

```
init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
 let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
 let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
 ...
}
```

Comment: let nyPerson = BackUp(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)

this line of code does that

Comment: I meant that your BackUp is not initialized, and nyPerson == nil.

Comment: indeed it is 

 init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {return nil}
guard let name = snapshotValue["name"] as? String else {return nil}
self.name = name
}